# How to initialize and keep value of updated js variable after page refresh using session storage?

Tags: javascript, null, session-storage

Previously, I had researched a way to make my js variables, team1score and team2score, retain it's value even after page refresh. The easiest solution that I found to my problem was using session storage. I now have my team1score and team2score retain its value so that problem was solved.

However, I now have another problem. The initial scores for both teams should be 0. Because I never initialized team1score and team2score to 0, the initial scores for both team are currently showing up as null. I wrote my code this way, because it was the only way the my js variables would retain their value.

Does anyone know how I can initialize team1score and team2score to 0, and at the same time retain their value after page refresh? Thanks in advance!

```
var team1score = sessionStorage.getItem('updatedScore1');   
var team2score = sessionStorage.getItem('updatedScore2');       

if(turn == 1)
{
    team1score += overallScore; 
    var teamOneScore = document.getElementById('team1score');
    alert('Team 1:'+team1score);

    //created new variable that stores the current updated score
    var updatedScore1 = team1score;

    //stores this into the local storage 
    sessionStorage.setItem('updatedScore1', updatedScore1);

    //retreives the variable from the local storage 
    var updatedScore1 = sessionStorage.getItem('updatedScore1');

    //displays this onto the html part of the code
    teamOneScore.innerHTML = 'Team 1: '+updatedScore1;

}
```

Comment: Do you want the score to be 0 if the turn == 0?

Comment: No, I'm sorry I may not have provided enough information.  if turn == 1 , then team 1 has won, update their score. Originally I had initialized team1score = 0 and this did show up correctly, but when I tried to get the js variable to retain its value  I changed it to team1score = sessionStorage.getItem('updateScore1'); Once I made this change, the js variable retained its value, but  team scores initially showed up as null. I believe this is because I never initialized them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shorthand if else using this

```
team1score = sessionStorage.getItem('updatedScore1') ? sessionStorage.getItem('updatedScore1') : 0;
```

Comment: It wasn't working initially because I had a small error I overlooked, but now it is!  Thanks so much!